# Drupal Go to ends in infinite redirects

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, redirect

I am using drupal go to in page.tpl.php if anonymous user tries to access /node/edit ,so that its redirected to /home page, this is how i am checking

```
  global $user;
if( $user->uid !=1 ){
    if($_REQUEST[q] =='node/edit'){
        echo "IN IF";
      drupal_goto('/', '', $fragment, 301);
    }else if($_REQUEST[q] =='node/edit/'){
      drupal_goto('/', '', $fragment, 301);
    }
}
```

But i will get this error

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

Comment: I got similar problem, is this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with this. Mainly, if you don't want anonymous users to be able to edit nodes, it's much better to use the permissions system to do it, instead of doing it in the theme layer. This video should help you with that:

http://gotdrupal.com/videos/understanding-drupal-permissions

To debug what's going on, I'd recommend Firefox's live HTTP headers extension. If you use that, it can show you where the redirect is going to. From the looks of it, you've made an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: didnt get how its an infinite loop ? once he goes from node/edit to / i.e home the if condition will fail the second time ,if i remove the go_to i will get the echo IN IF only once on my page

Comment: checked with HTTP extension it is in infinite loop